# Typescript types for middleware transformation pipe

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, pipeline, middleware

I'm trying to build a little function that enables middlewares (Express ones in this case) to transform the `Request` object by adding props to it, so any other following middleware on the chain can use them while maintaining the types.

Maybe it's easier to understand with an example:

```js
app.post(
  '/some/endpoint',
  pipeMiddleware(
    (req, res) => {
      // do some async stuff
      return { entity: { /* ... */ } }
    },
    (req, res) => {
      // do some async stuff
      return { otherEntity: { /* ... */ } }
    },
    (req, res) => handler(req.entity, req.otherEntity, req.body, res)
  )
)
```

So in that case, the second middleware will have access to `entity`, and the third one will have access to both `entity` & `otherEntity`.

I've managed to make it work by doing some ugly stuff like:

```js
type Dict = { [key: string]: any };

export const mw = <
  J extends Request,
  T extends Response,
  R extends Dict,
  K extends Dict | void,
  P extends Dict | void,
>(
  fn1: (a: J, a2: T) => Promise<R>,
  fn2: (a: J & R, a2: T) => Promise<K> = async () => ({} as any as K),
  fn3: (a: J & R & K, a2: T) => Promise<P> = async () => ({} as any as P),
) => async (arg1: J, arg2: T) => {
  const first = Object.assign(arg1, await fn1(arg1, arg2));
  const second = Object.assign(first, await fn2(first, arg2));
  const third = Object.assign(second, await fn3(second, arg2));
  return third;
};
```

And it actually returns the correct types, but I want to make it better by allowing to provide N number of parameters without having to update that function...

Comment: Your `mw` implementation is technically broken since it only passes the dict from the last function to the next one instead of the request with the dict.

Comment: it passes the extended object to each middleware, check `const second = Object.assign(first, await fn2(first, arg2));`, it's extending from `first` with the result of the second middleware

Comment: try using chaining or variable-argument overloads

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you probably don't actually want to modify the request. There is a specific field in the **response**, however, that's intended for this purpose: [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals). While it might seem odd to put data related to the request in the response object, think of the `Request` as an immutable representation of what the user sent to the server. Since that already happened, it should be considered as "set in stone".

The [type for request handlers](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9fff9068ade0aab5049fbbb55a22aa5ff31845cd/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L58-L71) (including middleware) has some rather gnarly generics, so this is going to get ugly...

First, let's start with what we're going to create. Ignoring all the generics, it's an object with 2 functions. The first, `createLocals` can be called repeatedly, and the returned object will be merged in to the `res.locals` value for the next step. Once all of these are complete, the other method `handle` will "finish the chain" and return a normal express `RequestHandler`.

It gets messy, because we want to be able to preserve any types that may have been set higher. So without further ado, the type for our handler chain:

```
type HandlerChain<
  P = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, never>,
> = {
  createLocals<R extends Record<string, any>>(
    fn: (
      req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>,
      res: Response<ResBody, Locals>,
    ) => R | Promise<R>,
  ): HandlerChain<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals & R>
  handle(
    handler: (
      req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>,
      res: Response<ResBody, Locals>,
    ) => void | Promise<void>,
  ): RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>
}
```

To save us from having to mix a bunch of types with the logic, let's also define a type for the function that creates one (this is a nice trick for complex functions):

```
type HandlerChainFn = {
  <
    P = ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
    Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
  >(): HandlerChain<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>
}
```

And finally, the implementation. `createLocals` just stores up all of the transformation functions, as they will only be used once `handle` is called. The type for `localsFns` doesn't matter, as we've already guaranteed the types when they were passed in.

Note that `createLocals` just casts `this` to the new return type. You could create new object here, but would need to allow passing the existing chain down, so this gets avoids that while still being functionally correct.

```
export const handlerChain: HandlerChainFn = () => {
  const localsFns: ((req: any, res: any) => any)[] = []

  return {
    createLocals(fn) {
      localsFns.push(fn)
      return this as any
    },
    handle(handler) {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        const handle = async () => {
          try {
            for (const fn of localsFns) {
              Object.assign(res.locals, await fn(req, res))
            }
            await handler(req, res)
            next()
          } catch (error) {
            next(error)
          }
        }
        void handle()
      }
    },
  }
}
```

While the definition is ugly, its usage is clean. All types are properly inferred all the way down the chain. You only (optionally) specify the input types, which gives you type safety for the query params and response body (or request body, if this were a post). The second example uses destructuring to keep it tidy. Also note that both sync and async functions are permitted for any of the calls.

```
type ReqQuery = { first: string; second: string }

type ResBody = {
  locals: { firstValue: string; secondValue: string }
}

app.get(
  '/test',
  handlerChain<any, ResBody, any, ReqQuery>()
    .createLocals((req) => {
      return Promise.resolve({
        firstValue: req.query.first.toUpperCase(),
      })
    })
    .createLocals(({ query }, { locals }) => ({
      secondValue: `last was ${locals.firstValue}, and next is ${query.second}`,
    }))
    .handle(async (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({ locals: res.locals })
    }),
)
```

The result:

```
$ curl 'localhost:3000/test?first=one&second=two'

{
  "locals": {
    "firstValue": "ONE",
    "secondValue": "last was ONE, and next is two"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative would be using Chainable Options

If you have a common challenge is TypeScript, someone probably already asked for a solution on https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges

Here's the explained solution for Chainable Options challenge:
https://ghaiklor.github.io/type-challenges-solutions/en/medium-chainable-options.html

---

Here's some writeup on that:

```
class ChainableExpress<Q extends Request = Request, S extends Response = Response> {
  app: Application
  middlewares: Array<(req: Q, res: S, next: NextFunction) => any> = []
  constructor(app: Application) {
    this.app = app
  }

  pipe<R extends SomeRecord, V extends Q = (R & Q) extends Q ? (R & Q) : never>(
    middleware: (req: Q, res: S) => MaybePromise<R>,
  ): ChainableExpress<V, S> {
    const chain = new ChainableExpress<V, S>(this.app)
    chain.middlewares = this.middlewares.concat(middleware)
    return chain
  }

  constructHandler(handler: (req: Q, res: S, next: NextFunction) => void): RequestHandler {
    return (async (req: Q, res: S, next: NextFunction) => {
      for (const m of this.middlewares) {
        req = Object.assign(req, await m(req, res, next))
      }
      handler(req, res, next)
    }) as any as RequestHandler
  }

  post(path: string, handler: (req: Q, res: S, next: NextFunction) => void): this {
    app.post(path, this.constructHandler(handler));
    return this
  }
}
let app!: Application
new ChainableExpress(app)
  .pipe((q, s) => ({ a: 1 }))
  .pipe(async (q, s) => ({ b: q.a + 1 }))
  .post('/some/endpoint', (q, s, n) => {
    s.setHeader('a', q.a)
    s.setHeader('b', q.b)
    n()
  })
```